# Sitecore link to another page and also pass an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I am working on a Sitecore project. I have an item in sitecore called Landing-page. Landing-page has an empty layout; with one placeholder. I have attached to this placeholder one controller rendering. From this controller rendering the whole of Landing-page is generated.

The main purpose of Landing page is to show all offers. Offers is of type Multilist. I have made Offers a multilist field on the Landing-page item.

In my single controller rendering method I am using:

```
var Sitecoreoffers = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField)item.Fields["Offers"];
```

To access landing-page's Offer fields. In my action method that the controller rendering points to. I have constructed my own viewmodel that takes the Offers from the Sitecore item landing-page field and equals it to a C# List data type.

```
var Sitecoreoffers = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField)item.Fields["Offers"];
```

What I want to do now is when the user clicks on an offer I get redirected to a offer detail page. In order to do this; I want to send the offer id to the Action Method; so that I can then access all of the offer's fields in the offer detail page. In C# you have the @html.ActionLink which is what I am currently implementing. Are there any advise about the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Given that in your implementation offers are "detail pages" themselves, the right way to link to them in your Sitecore site would be to generate a regular `<a href>` to those pages and let the browser perform a full page request to them.

The Sitecore API provides a class called **LinkManager** that has a static method called **GetItemUrl** which takes an object of type **Sitecore.Data.Items.Item** and returns a friendly URL to the item.

In your case, you would loop over the objects in your `Sitecoreoffers` collection and you would use `LinkManager.GetItemUrl` to get the friendly URL for each.  You can then have a `foreach` loop in your razor file that generates the A tags for each Sitecore item in your `Sitecoreoffers` object.